# Одно- или двусоставное предложение? Из чего оно состоит?

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, члены-предложения

Делая упражнение по русскому языку, наткнулся на следующую формулировку.
Определите вид ОДНОСОСТАВНОГО предложения: **Но вот что странно**.

Разве данное предложение  является односоставным? На мой взгляд, сочетание "вот что" является цельным подлежащим.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: Интересный вопрос, который говорит о наблюдательности  и умении  мыслить самостоятельно. Я думаю, что сообщество должно отметить  это положительным голосованием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Рассмотрим полное предложение (всегда приводите полный текст): ***Но вот что странно: Митя этот сам попросился домой, отец приехал и взял его из лагеря.***

2) Вы правы, первое предложение **не является  односоставным,** но почему же ошиблись составители? Как вариант, они могли посчитать ЧТО союзом, но это не союз, **а союзное слово**. И союзное слово здесь выступает **в роли подлежащего.**

***Но*** — присоединительный союз, ***вот*** — частица, ***что*** — подлежащее, ***странно*** — именное сказуемое, выраженное краткой формой прилагательного.

3) Но тогда надо определить **грамматику** сложного предложения. В нем стоит двоеточие, но связь союзная (с помощью союзного слова), значит, это СПП.

4) Но СПП не совсем обычное, так как **присоединительное придаточное стоит на первом месте.**

Сравним: Но в двенадцать часов ночи он засобирался домой, что странно. [Токарева Виктория. Своя правда // «Новый Мир», 2002]

В этом предложение присоединительное придаточное на месте, а в нашем предложении **инверсия**. Поэтому это специальная "акцентирующая" конструкция, нечто среднее между придаточным присоединительным, изъяснительным и местоименным.

(Грамматический анализ взят из учебника Кустовой "Синтаксис современного русского языка").

Таким образом, делаем вывод: первое предложение **двусоставное**,  ЧТО — это союзное слово в роли **подлежащего**.

Comment: Но если это отдельное предложение, то анализ должен быть немного другим.  Это предложение не является самостоятельным по смыслу, то есть требует обязательного продолжения. (Это похоже на парцелляцию). В таком случае ЧТО также является местоименным подлежащим, но относится оно уже к содержанию следующего предложения.

Comment: Плюс Вы немного ошиблись, когда  писали про союзную связь: "В нем стоит двоеточие, но связь союзная (с помощью СОЮЗНОГО СЛОВА)" Здесь в роли связки выступает сочинительный союз "но". Чтобы пояснить, приведу пример: "Митя этот сам попросился домой, но ЭТО(чтобы не путать сочетанием "вот что" странно" Здесь "но" просто соединяет два предложения, как я считаю.

Comment: Хорошо, не будем углубляться в другие темы, но я сделаю для себя вывод.  Прежде чем анализировать что-то, надо иметь полный текст. В данном случае его у меня не было. Приведенное предложение - это только его часть.

Answer (score 0):

А переставить?

*Странно вот что...* Наблюдаем лёгкую инверсию.

---

[Односоставные по структуре предложения - это полные предложения. У них не пропущен второй член: второй главный член не нужен для понимания смысла предложения.](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/707-18_dvusostavnye_i_odnosostavnye_predlozheniya_tipy_odnosostavnyh_predlozhenii.html)

Я сейчас табличку нарисую (срисую), а  Вы выбирайте, наблюдаем ли мы составное именное сказуемое с именной частью – наречием ***странно*** (что? - а вот что).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ещё примеры - какие части речи могут выражать именную часть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итого. Именная часть может быть выражена всеми частями речи, кроме глагола в личной форме и деепричастия.