# А вот(,) что меня пугает

Tags: пунктуация

А вот(,) что меня пугает.

+++++

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Одно - или двусоставное предложение? Из чего оно состоит?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452078/%d0%9e%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%98%d0%b7-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82)

Answer (score 1):

*А вот что меня пугает.*

Большой толковый словарь на "Грамоте.ру" утверждает, что ВОТ - это указательная частица, а  частицы запятыми не выделяются:

> ВОТ, частица. 1. Указывает на кого-, что-л., находящееся или
>   происходящее перед глазами, в непосредственной близости или при
>   рассказывании как бы перед глазами. Вот и наш поезд. Вот вам ключ. Вот
>   те крест (страстное уверение, клятва в чём-л.). Где ваш дом? - Вот
>   (сопровождается указательным жестом). * Вот Бог, а вот порог (Погов.).
>   Вот парадный подъезд (Некрасов).
>
> **2. (обычно ударная) (с местоим. и нареч.). Употребляется для уточнения и усиления значения последующего слова или высказывания в
>   целом.** *Вот что я тебе скажу. Вот по какому поводу мы собрались. Вот на
>   кого надежда. Вот в чём вопрос.* 
>   http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?all=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82

Это простое предложение. Запятую мы бы поставили в сложном предложении, где придаточное относилось бы к указательному местоимению ТО, а не к частице:

*А вот то, что меня пугает.*